# The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'AppState'. pics with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

### Hello everyone.

I was studying "Dart and Flutter: The Complete Developer's Guide" on Udemy.

And this error showed up, I have no idea how to fix this error. Everyone on the Q&A says this course isn't updated, so if any of u guys know. Please help me fix this error.

```
    // Import flutter helper library
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'models/image_models.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'widgets/image_list.dart';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return AppState();
  }
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<ImageModel> images = [];

  void fetchImage() async {
    counter++;
    var response =
        await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/$counter');
    var imageModel = ImageModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

    setState(() {
      images.add(imageModel);
    });
  }

// Must define a 'build' method that returns the widget that 'this' widget will show
  Widget build(context) {
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ImageList(images),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.switch_access_shortcut_add),
          onPressed: fetchImage,
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Lets see some People!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error 1 : The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'AppState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'.

Error 2 : The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

#### Here's the full code , you can access it from my repository [Here](https://github.com/kisekifrans/Simple-Pics-Apps)

### Thankyou and have a great day!

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is. You are calling a method named `get`. A method with that name doesn't exist. You need to make one if you want to call it.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you will need to add a "return" to your widget's build method:

```
Widget build(context) {
 return MaterialApp( // Add return here
  home: Scaffold(
    body: ImageList(images),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.switch_access_shortcut_add),
      onPressed: fetchImage,
    ),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Expletive'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}